# How to reset locked user in SAP ITS server?

Tags: locking, sap-basis

We have this ITS SAP server hosted in Windows Server 2003 and our support on this already left us without transitioning the application. Now we got Name or password is incorrect/ locked out see below picture. We already unlock the user / reset the password in SAP but it is not reflecting to the web application. I need to what file where the user name and password is located so I can change it with the new SAP username and password.

Below are the current location of SAP in our server.

C:\Program Files\SAP\ITS\6.20

C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\PRD\sap\its

[image: Password Locked]

Please help thanks!

Comment: Check `USR02` table in ERP, what is the value of `UFLAG` for that user? Maybe there is database deadlock, though you always can change that field manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now fixed the problem.

Below are the steps:

1. Reset the password in SAP
2. Stop ITS SAP Service
3. Open and change global and zvwi in ITS Web Studio
4. Copy and paste the updated files to the production ITS PRD services folder
5. Restart the ITS SAP Service

Answer (score 0):

You may have reset the password, but clearly it's not unlocked. Unlock the user, then login using SAP GUI before you try the ITS service again.